# Positioning Labels in Asymptote

Tags: labels, asymptote

How can I control the position of the `$x$` label below? Created with `draw("$x$",O--X,blue,Arrow3)`

I know I can manually control label positions with `label("$x$",<position>,blue)`, but is there a more automatic way---something analogous to the `tikz` options `node[near end]` or `node[midway, above]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{asy}[width=0.5\textwidth]
import graph3;
import grid3;
currentprojection=perspective(-0.51,3,1,up=Z);

draw("$x$",O--X,blue,Arrow3); 
draw(O--Y,green,Arrow3); 
draw(O--Z,red,Arrow3);
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `point(path,p)` to make it slightly more automatic.  eg `label("$x$",align=N,point(O--X,0.8));`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass a `Label` object to `draw()` instead of a simple string.  The `Label()` constructor takes options (among others) `position` and `align`.  In particular, passing it the option `position=Relative(0.2)`, for instance, instructs Asymptote to draw the label 20% of the way along the path.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}[width=0.5\textwidth]
settings.render=4;
settings.prc=false;
import three;
currentprojection=perspective(-0.51,3,1,up=Z);

draw(L=Label("$x$", position=Relative(0.8), align=N), O--X, blue, Arrow3); 
draw(O--Y,green,Arrow3); 
draw(O--Z,red,Arrow3);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Just curious: Why might it be useful to name the label L? Why might you refer to it later?

Comment: I'm not naming the label; I'm using key-value syntax. This frees me from having to remember the order of the arguments of the `draw()` command. In particular, in my own code, I almost always put the path as the first argument.