# Building with asymptote: file-2.tex not found, null surface

Tags: errors, compiling, warnings, asymptote

I keep getting these weird errors when trying to compile with Asymptote. I compile with pdflatex, then asymptote, then pdflatex. The error is as stated in the title. For example, when building `latexusage.tex` (the example asymptote file), it says that on `line 91` `file 'latexusage-2.tex' not found`. The first and last figures are displayed in the produced pdf but the 3D cube is missing. Any ideas what I'm missing?

To install, I used the instructions in [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83035/using-asymptote-with-miktex) by Speravir.

It seems the `-2.tex` is supposed to be the tex file for the second image. The `-2.asy` and `-2.out` files are created and in the folder, just not the `-2.tex` file.

Edit: after trying to make a MWE I'm getting the error `C:\Program Files (x86)\Asymptote/three_surface.asy: 906.10: null surface` on this code (no error if I delete the label line though):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}

\begin{asydef}
import three;
usepackage("bm");
texpreamble("\def\V#1{\bm{#1}}");
\end{asydef}

\begin{asy}
draw(unitcube,blue);
label("$V-E+F=2$",(0,1,0.5),3Y,blue+fontsize(17pt));
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: Perhaps it is the bug related to Ghostscript version. Please specify Asymptote version and Ghotscript version. See also https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/bugs/180/ (closed in the version).

Comment: Asymptote: 2.32. Ghostscript: 9.15. It looks like that is probably the problem, considering my versions! I'm not seeing a version 2.33 available. I did find [the r5691 commit](http://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/code/5691/) mentioned although I'm not sure if I can just change those files without breaking anything else.

Comment: Actually, I don't even know which files I'd have to change for that commit. =P

Comment: Please see this link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204070/labels-in-3d-mode-dont-work-in-asymptote I always embedd Asymptote code this way: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&p=57950