# texpath command returns empty array in Asymptote

Tags: miktex, asymptote

when using the `texpath` command in Asymptote, I only get an empty path array. I'm using a miktex installation on a Windows 8 machine, ghostscript is installed. (I also have a TeX Live installation on a Linux machine where this works fine).

edit: Here's a simple example, where this problem shows up:

```
draw(texpath("Hello, World!"));
label(string(texpath("Hello, World!").length), (0,0));
```

The resulting pdf-file (and also the resulting eps-file) shows a single 0.

edit 2: I'm using ghostscript version 9.16 (32bit, but the same problem occurs with the 64-bit version).

Comment: Could you give us an example of a problematic program using this module?

Comment: Please specify ghostscript version. I think texpath uses ghostscript (or pstricks) so the odd behavior is related to the bug (asy uses a deprecated gs driver). The bug is solved in the svn version (see asy svn page). There are also another messages here about it.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239370/building-with-asymptote-file-2-tex-not-found-null-surface and the link. So you have to wait the new compiled version or downgrade ghostscript (under windows).

Comment: @O.G.: Downgrading ghostscript worked for me---thanks a lot! Please turn your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hy

A new version of Asymptote, v2.33, was released today. From the update

> A work around was implemented for the missing epswrite driver in ghostscript-9.15.

So it seems that you can use Ghostscript >=9.15 and Asymptote 2.33

Old message :
See [Building with asymptote: file-2.tex not found, null surface](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239370/building-with-asymptote-file-2-tex-not-found-null-surface) and also [Labels in 3D mode don't work in Asymptote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204070/labels-in-3d-mode-dont-work-in-asymptote).
So you have to wait the new compiled version or downgrade ghostscript (under windows).